# Singleton implementation in Swift 2 no longer works for Swift 3

Tags: singleton, swift3

This worked in Swift 2 but causes an error in Swift 3...

```
    class SomeClass {

        var Role: Int
        var Status: Bool

        static let sharedClass = SomeClass()

        private init(){
            Role = 3
            Status = false
        }
    }

   let shared = SomeClass() //error on this line -> SomeClass initializer is inaccesible due to private protection level
```

I can remove the `private` keyword from the `init()` but I am not sure if that is still a proper singleton implementation. Does anybody know what the right way to do this in Swift 3 is? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
let shared = SomeClass()
```

isn't using the singleton. It's attempting to create a new instance of `SomeClass`. And it fails because the `init` is private.

You want:

```
let shared = SomeClass.sharedClass
```

That makes use of the singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use `SomeClass()` at all, that's the whole point: your singleton is only accessible via

```
SomeClass.sharedClass
```

and this is on purpose: the *same instance* is shared and used in different places.